# No view found for a Drawer Screen in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

**What i am doing**:: I am inflating the menu drawer activity in this screen

**What is happening**:: I am getting the error as shown in log as no view, 
What is happening & How to resolve this

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    FragmentTransaction ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hive_activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                //// calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            MenuDrawerFragSortingHome fragment0 = MenuDrawerFragSortingHome.newInstance("SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC","PRESSED_RATE_ASC-NULL_PRICE_NULL-NULL_DISTANCE_NULL-DATA");
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment0);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 1:
            MenuDrawerFragAccount fragment1=MenuDrawerFragAccount.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 2:
            MenuDrawerFragSortingHome fragment2 = MenuDrawerFragSortingHome.newInstance("SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC","PRESSED_RATE_ASC-NULL_PRICE_NULL-NULL_DISTANCE_NULL-DATA");
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 3:
            MenuDrawerFragment4 fragment3=MenuDrawerFragment4.newInstance("SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC","PRESSED_RATE_ASC-NULL_PRICE_NULL-NULL_DISTANCE_NULL-DATA");
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 4:
            FilterBuffetFragment fragment4=FilterBuffetFragment.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment4);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;

        case 5:
            MenuDrawerFragSearch fragment5=MenuDrawerFragSearch.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment5);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        /*case 6:
            MenuDrawerFragFeatured fragment6=MenuDrawerFragFeatured.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment6);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 7:
            MenuDrawerFragDeals fragment7=MenuDrawerFragDeals.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment7);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 8:
            MenuDrawerFragInvite fragment8=MenuDrawerFragInvite.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment8);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;  */
        }
        ft.commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 *///

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

**Log**::

```
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.MenuDrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a003c (info.androidhive.slidingmenu:id/content_frame) for fragment MenuDrawerFragSortingHome{415cad70 #0 id=0x7f0a003c}
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a003c (info.androidhive.slidingmenu:id/content_frame) for fragment MenuDrawerFragSortingHome{415cad70 #0 id=0x7f0a003c}
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)
05-19 22:15:53.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 11 more
```

**hive_activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Show us this layout: `hive_activity_main`.

Comment: Based on the log, the issue is in `displayView(int)` where `ft.replace()` is being called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because there is no `View` with the id `R.id.content_frame` in your layout. You only have a `View` called `R.id.frame_container`. Your `FragmentTransactions` need to look like this:

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        MenuDrawerFragSortingHome fragment0 = MenuDrawerFragSortingHome.newInstance("SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC", "PRESSED_RATE_ASC-NULL_PRICE_NULL-NULL_DISTANCE_NULL-DATA");
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment0);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;

    case 1:
        MenuDrawerFragAccount fragment1 = MenuDrawerFragAccount.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment1);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;

    case 2:
        MenuDrawerFragSortingHome fragment2 = MenuDrawerFragSortingHome.newInstance("SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC", "PRESSED_RATE_ASC-NULL_PRICE_NULL-NULL_DISTANCE_NULL-DATA");
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;

    case 3:
        MenuDrawerFragment4 fragment3 = MenuDrawerFragment4.newInstance("SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC", "PRESSED_RATE_ASC-NULL_PRICE_NULL-NULL_DISTANCE_NULL-DATA");
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment3);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;

    case 4:
        FilterBuffetFragment fragment4 = FilterBuffetFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment4);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;

    case 5:
        MenuDrawerFragSearch fragment5 = MenuDrawerFragSearch.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment5);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;
}
```

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions or problems feel free to ask!

Comment: @ Xaver Kapeller ... Oops ! .... How did i miss that (guess i was debugging only java code, i didn't observe xml)! ... You have razor sharp eyes ! .... thanks ... I resolved it :)

Comment: You actually just have to look at the logcat, in 99% of all cases it tells you exactly what's wrong, in your case: `...No view found for id 0x7f0a003c (info.androidhive.slidingmenu:id/content_frame) for...`. So it was pretty obvious what to look for :D

Answer (score 2):

In a `DrawerLayout`, the `FragmentTransaction` replaces the `FrameLayout` with the `Fragment`. So in your java code in `ft.replace(R.id.content_view......)` `R.id.content_view` is the `FrameLayout`. And the id of your `FrameLayout` is `R.id.frame_container`. Make that change and your code will work